# Merge 2 objects where Key1 = Key 2 and assign Value1 as key to Value 2

Tags: javascript

I have 2 objects like this

```
{
    "2-14": "text-body",
    "3-28": "h1",
    "3-30": "h2",
    "3-36": "color-primary",
    "3-38": "color-secondary",
    "3-40": "color-black-100",
    "3-43": "color-black-50"
}
```

and

```
{
    "3-36": "#4992FF",
    "3-38": "#49DEFF",
    "3-40": "#000000",
    "3-43": "#808080"
}
```

I need to merge these two like below

```
{
  "color-primary": "#4992FF",
  "color-secondary": "#49DEFF",
  "color-black-100": "#000000",
  "color-black-50": "#808080",
}
```

Basically, Value of the first object will be key and the value of second object will become value of new object. I need to merge where key matches. Please help.

I tried this way to merge both. But not able to get new object as required.

```
const newArray = {};
for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(array1)) {
  newArray[key] = array2[key];
}
```

this gives me

```
{
    "3-36": "color-primary",
    "3-38": "color-secondary",
    "3-40": "color-black-100",
    "3-43": "color-black-50"
}
```

Comment: What did you try this far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a short remark: You are not dealing with Arrays here, but Objects.

Here is a pretty basic solution that should give you what you are loooking for:

```js
const obj1 = {
  "2-14": "text-body",
  "3-28": "h1",
  "3-30": "h2",
  "3-36": "color-primary",
  "3-38": "color-secondary",
  "3-40": "color-black-100",
  "3-43": "color-black-50"
};

const obj2 = {
  "3-36": "#4992FF",
  "3-38": "#49DEFF",
  "3-40": "#000000",
  "3-43": "#808080"
};

const result = { };

Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key => {
  if (obj2[key]) {
    result[obj1[key]] = obj2[key];
  }
});
```

The result will be:

```json
{
  "color-primary": "#4992FF",
  "color-secondary": "#49DEFF",
  "color-black-100": "#000000",
  "color-black-50": "#808080"
}
```

Comment: Wow! that was quick and this is what exactly I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
const names = {
    "2-14": "text-body",
    "3-28": "h1",
    "3-30": "h2",
    "3-36": "color-primary",
    "3-38": "color-secondary",
    "3-40": "color-black-100",
    "3-43": "color-black-50"
}

const colors = {
    "3-36": "#4992FF",
    "3-38": "#49DEFF",
    "3-40": "#000000",
    "3-43": "#808080"
}

const result = {};

Object.entries(colors).forEach(color => {
  const [key, value] = color;
  if(key in names) {
    result[names[key]] = value;
  }
})

/*
{
  "color-primary": "#4992FF",
  "color-secondary": "#49DEFF",
  "color-black-100": "#000000",
  "color-black-50": "#808080",
}
*/
```

Comment: Tried this too and worked as expected!. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

this is my try;

```
const obj1 = {
    "2-14": "text-body",
    "3-28": "h1",
    "3-30": "h2",
    "3-36": "color-primary",
    "3-38": "color-secondary",
    "3-40": "color-black-100",
    "3-43": "color-black-50"
}
const obj2= {
    "3-36": "#4992FF",
    "3-38": "#49DEFF",
    "3-40": "#000000",
    "3-43": "#808080"
}
const objFinal = {};
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(k => {
  if (obj2[k]){
    objFinal[obj1[k]]=obj2[k];
  }
});
console.log(objFinal);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const names = {
  "2-14": "text-body",
  "3-28": "h1",
  "3-30": "h2",
  "3-36": "color-primary",
  "3-38": "color-secondary",
  "3-40": "color-black-100",
  "3-43": "color-black-50"
};
const colors = {
  "3-36": "#4992FF",
  "3-38": "#49DEFF",
  "3-40": "#000000",
  "3-43": "#808080"
};

// find all keys that are present in both object
const keysToMerge = [];
Object.keys(names).forEach(key => Boolean(colors[key]) && keysToMerge.push(key));

// merge them
const result = {};
keysToMerge.forEach(key => result[names[key]] = colors[key]);
```